# using react-md with meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to use https://react-md.mlaursen.com in my meteor app. I got the functionality but not the style.

I create a simple example with a `drawer` component and all the items are present except

### the drawer looks ugly:

[image]

### instead of pretty:

[image]

I suspect the CSS is missing but I don't know how to add it. react-md uses SASS and I added https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss for that.

#### the code for the menu is:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'react-md/lib/Drawers';
import Button from 'react-md/lib/Buttons/Button';
import Toolbar from 'react-md/lib/Toolbars';
import FontIcon from 'react-md/lib/FontIcons';

export default class SimpleExample extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visible: false,
            position: 'left',
        };

        this.inboxListItems = [{
            key: 'inbox',
            primaryText: 'Inbox',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>inbox</FontIcon>,
            active: true,
        }, {
            key: 'starred',
            primaryText: 'Starred',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>star</FontIcon>,
        }, {
            key: 'send-mail',
            primaryText: 'Send mail',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>send</FontIcon>,
        }, {
            key: 'drafts',
            primaryText: 'Drafts',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>drafts</FontIcon>,
        }, { key: 'divider', divider: true }, {
            key: 'all-mail',
            primaryText: 'All mail',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>mail</FontIcon>,
        }, {
            key: 'trash',
            primaryText: 'Trash',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>delete</FontIcon>,
        }, {
            key: 'spam',
            primaryText: 'Spam',
            leftIcon: <FontIcon>info</FontIcon>,
        }];


        this._toggleLeft = this._toggleLeft.bind(this);
        this._toggleRight = this._toggleRight.bind(this);
        this._closeDrawer = this._closeDrawer.bind(this);
        this._handleToggle = this._handleToggle.bind(this);
    }

    _handleToggle(visible) {
        this.setState({ visible });
    }

    _closeDrawer() {
        this.setState({ visible: false });
    }

    _toggleLeft() {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, position: 'left' });
    }

    _toggleRight() {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, position: 'right' });
    }

    render() {
        const left = this.state.position === 'left';
        const close = <Button icon onClick={this._closeDrawer}>{left ? 'arrow_back' : 'close'}</Button>;
        const header = (
            <Toolbar
                nav={left ? null : close}
                actions={left ? close : null}
                className="md-divider-border md-divider-border--bottom"
            />
        );
        return (
            <div className="md-grid">
                <Button raised label="Toggle Drawer Left" onClick={this._toggleLeft} />
                <Button raised label="Toggle Drawer Right" onClick={this._toggleRight} />
                <Drawer
                    {...this.state}
                    navItems={this.inboxListItems}
                    onVisibilityToggle={this._handleToggle}
                    type={Drawer.DrawerTypes.TEMPORARY}
                    header={header}
                    style={{ zIndex: 100 }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to import the specific styles to your component? If you are using npm, use `require('node/module/path/to/style.css')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing css files of the module. I think it is best to include them in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-md/dist/react-md.indigo-pink.min.css">
```

The file name is in this format `react-md.${PRIMARY_COLOR}-${ACCENT_COLOR}.min.css`. Follow it when you need to change the color.

in order to get the fonts and icons, also add

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700%7CMaterial+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```